# Products of a dictionary can not be repeated odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

I'm taking a shot of all my products that were sold in the current month and I store it in a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
a = [
    {'product_name':'coca-cola','qty':2},
    {'product_name':'pepsi','qty':2},
    {'product_name':'coca-cola','qty':1},
    {'product_name':'coca-cola','qty':1},
    {'product_name':'coca-cola1','qty':1},
    {'product_name':'pepsi','qty':2}
    ]
```

Now I'm trying to make the products do not repeat, the candid is that if you repeat the product you should simply add the amount leaving the dictionary like this:

```
result =[{'product_name':'coca-cola','qty':4},{'product_id':'pepsi','qty':4},{'product_id':'coca-colca1','qty':1}]
```

So far I have only tried to do the following but the result is not appropriate:

```
b = []

for index  in range(0,len(a)-1):
    if  a[index]['product_name'] != a[index + 1 ]['product_name']:
        b.append(a[index])


print b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following;

```
a = [
    {'product_name':'coca-cola','qty':2},
    {'product_name':'pepsi','qty':2},
    {'product_name':'coca-cola','qty':1},
    {'product_name':'coca-cola','qty':1},
    {'product_name':'coca-cola1','qty':1},
    {'product_name':'pepsi','qty':2}
    ]

b = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]['product_name'] not in b : b.append(a[i]['product_name'])

for j in range(len(b)):
    qty = 0
    for k in range(len(a)):
        if a[k]['product_name'] == b[j] : qty += a[k]['qty']
    b[j] = {'product_name':b[j], 'qty':qty}

print(b)
```

I first looped through and entered the unique product names as strings into the list initialized with b. Then I looped through each of the unique product names in list b and then summed up the quantity associated with that product name in list a. Finally I then turned the string entry into a dictionary with the existing product name and the total quantity.

**output**

```
b = [
    {'product_name': 'coca-cola', 'qty': 4},
    {'product_name': 'pepsi', 'qty': 4},
    {'product_name': 'coca-cola1', 'qty': 1}
    ]
```

Comment: thansk .this is solution

Comment: I'm surprised that you accepted this answer man. More line of code and more complexity in both running and logic. I think the left two answer are way better than this one wired!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to use two steps: First, get the totals and then generate the output in the format you need.

```
    a = [
        {'product_name':'coca-cola','qty':2},
        {'product_name':'pepsi','qty':2},
        {'product_name':'coca-cola','qty':1},
        {'product_name':'coca-cola','qty':1},
        {'product_name':'coca-cola1','qty':1},
        {'product_name':'pepsi','qty':2}
        ]

    totals = {}
    for sale in a:
        if sale['product_name'] in totals.keys():
            totals[sale['product_name']] += sale['qty']
        else:
            totals[sale['product_name']] = sale['qty']

    b = []
    for product_name, qty in totals.items():
        b.append({'product_name':product_name, 'qty':qty})
```